# Java: Load multiple properties files as one

Tags: java, file

Sorry if the title is unclear.

What I'm trying to do is load configuration files "on top of each other".

Say I have Config #1:

`config.property=Something Here`

And Config #2:

`config.otherproperty=Other Thingy Here`

And the java app loads it as this:

`config.property=Something Here`

`config.otherproperty=Other Thingy Here`

As though it was all one file.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am unclear as to what you really need.  If I understood you correctly, you want to load two properties file into a single `Properties` object.  If this is the case, the all you have to do is something like this:

```
PropsDemo demo = new PropsDemo();
String prop1 = "config1.properties";
String prop2 = "config2.properties";

Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream input1 = demo.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(prop1);
InputStream input2 = demo.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(prop2);
try
{
    props.load(input1);
    props.load(input2);
    System.out.println(props.toString());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
}
```

The file ***config1.properties*** contains:

```
color=blue
```

And the file ***config2.properties*** contains:

```
shape=circle
```

The snippet above outputs:

```
{shape=circle, color=blue}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `java.util.Properties` with the `defaults` constructor parameter. Whichever one should over-ride the other in the event of any conflicts should be constructed last, with the other as the `defaults.`

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Say I have two text files, one that says `hello world` and another that says `hello nobody`. How can I make it so that my app reads `hello world hello nobody` as though it were one file?