# Sharing common properties across different property files in Java

Tags: java, properties-file

I have two properties files in my Java project. Both of them have some common properties, e.g.

```
PropertyFile1.properties
    p1=v1
    p2=v2
    p3=v3
    p4=v4
PropertyFile2.properties
    p1=v1
    p2=v2
    p23=v23
    p24=v24
```

Here, p1 and p2 properties are common to both files.

I need to be able to separate out such common properties in a different file, e.g.

```
Common.properties
    p1=v1
    p2=v2
```

And then refer this common.properties inside PropertyFile1 and PropertyFile2.properties files.
Basically, I need to be able to inherit the common properties and their values across different property files.
Is this possible?

I've come across following link but not sure how to use it for my requirement.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this in the files. You only can load multiple property files into a ``Properties`` object.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use this property object? and where do i pass it to?

Comment: First, have a look at the [Javadoc for ``java.util.Properties``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Then follow this question on Stackoverflow: [Java: Load multiple properties files as one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706162/java-load-multiple-properties-files-as-one)

Answer (score 0):

Properties is a file extension for files mainly used in Java related technologies to store the **configurable parameters** of an application. The advantage of using properties file is, we can configure things which are environment specific (or are prone to change over a period of time) without the need of changing anything in code. Hence inheriting common properties is **not a good approach**. *If a property seems to be static for all e.g. environments, then it shouldn't be a property.*

But, it could be we have multiple development environments and production, where we would **share same properties in the environments meant for development** purposes and different properties for production. In this case we could create a common properties file and inherit it in all our environment specific properties files. Another scenario could be, that **at the moment of development the property is same for all environments**, but we would like to provide the option of changing it in the future, when required.

There are two ways to inherit properties from a common properties file:

- **include**
- **includeOptional**

The value of these properties is the name of a file on the disk, that file will be included into the configuration. The difference between *"include"* and *"includeOptional"* is that if the file value is absent, processing continues with *"includeOptional"* but stops with *"include"*.